# Is there a way to get percentage for earch field

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I need percentage for each status

```
Select NAME, STATUS, Count(*) From DATA 

group by NAME, STATUS
order by NAME
```

[image: Result is here]

[image: I need percentage for each of the statues]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create subquery for count without status, then you need to get percentage user wise, you can try this below:

```
Select f1.NAME, f1.STATUS, Count(*),CONCAT((Count(*)*100)/(select Count(*) from data f2 where NAME=f1.Name group by f2.NAME),'%') From DATA f1

group by f1.NAME, f1.STATUS
order by f1.NAME
```

Or if you have user id then it's better query and perfect result

```
Select f1.NAME, f1.STATUS, Count(*),CONCAT((Count(*)*100)/(select Count(*) from data f2 where UserId=f1.UserId group by f2.UserId),'%') From DATA f1

group by f1.UserId,f1.NAME, f1.STATUS
order by f1.NAME
```

Comment: Thanks Dhaval but my table has more than 1 name

Comment: I have change code you need to pass Name in the subquery and If you have  userid then pass in where condition.

Comment: Dhaval, this works, can you help me with how to round and add % symbol at last

Comment: You can add % like this. with concat function in sql. I have added code in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you have used below formula in your percentage calculate,
count(row first count)*100/sum of all count rows, i.e.448*100/1560=28.71.
So, dear, I request you please mention all the problems with your question.

Try the below query and enjoy it.

```
 Select NAME, STATUS, Count(*),
     Count(*)*100/(select sum(CT) from (select NAME, STATUS, Count(*) CT from data group by NAME, STATUS))PERCENTAGE
     From DATA 
       group by NAME, STATUS
        order by NAME
```

Comment: Thanks but my table has more than 1 name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the percentage. First is to get the total `count()`, then multiple by `1.0`, to cast the result in `decimal` format.

```
select name, status, count(1) 
    ,  ((count(1) * 1.0)
        /(select count(1) from data)) * 100 as percentage
from data
group by name, status
order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this, using SUM to calculate the total and then use group by to group the names

```
SELECT name, status, COUNT(status)/(
    SELECT COUNT(status) 
    FROM data
)*100
FROM percentage
GROUP BY name, status
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: i think this query has not properly worked, A group function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, was used within another group function, as in MAX(COUNT(*)), without a corresponding GROUP BY clause. Either add a GROUP BY clause or remove the extra level of nesting.